# How to update Email Opt Out field?

Tags: apex, email, update, upsert

Is there any way to update the **Email Opt out** field ?
this is OOTB field in SF but when i trying to save my code IDE told my

> " field is not writeable"

The API name is **IsEmailBounced**

Answer (score 2):

**IsEmailBounced** and the email opt out fields are different things. **IsEmailBounced** refers to the [deliverability settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_bounce_enable.htm&type=5) - if bounce management is activated, the field value is updated to true.

The field you're looking for is **HasOptedOutOfEmail** on the Lead and Contact objects. You can update that field as normal provided you have the correct permissions.

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to SFSE!